# Having trouble solving a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\left(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)x}\right)$

I've tried a couple of things but I can't get to the right result.. according to online calculators the limit equals $\frac{1}{ln\left(2\right)}$ but I keep getting 0. Is there a a trick to solve it?

Comment: Take the limits for the numerator and the denominator separately.

Comment: expand numerator and denumerator with $2^x$

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\left(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)x}\right)$

taking $1/x$=$t$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$, $t$ tends to $0$

then apply L-hopital rule or use $lim_{t\to0}\frac{2^t-1}{t}$ = $ln2$

Comment: Thank you so much I completely forgot about substitution method! :)